# In Bitcoin Core, how do nodes transmit blocks, either in parallel or in series?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoin-core-development

In Bitcoin Core, do nodes transmit blocks sequentially to adjacent nodes, or is it a parallel transmission where blocks are sent to multiple nodes simultaneously? Additionally, could you provide information on the specific implementation details and the corresponding sections of the code?

Comment: You asked almost the same question recently: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/121172/5406. Could you please clarify how your questions differ?

Comment: Is there something you can't find when you looked at the public source code of the software you referenced in your question tags?